# Arrival-side amenities at Istanbul Sabiha Gökçen International Airport for waiting

Tags: istanbul, saw

I had seen more than a few airports having really meagre facilities landside, so I thought I will ask: I will land at 14:55 at Istanbul Sabiha Gökçen International Airport (SAW) from Zurich and will need to wait for people who will land at 16:20 arriving from Budapest, both on Pegasus airlines. Where could I wait? Cafe, lounge, something like that. I have a Priority Pass card and not afraid to use it :)

Comment: People seem to have posted videos of themselves at the airport (on YouTube) so if nobody answers you may strike lucky there.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't experienced myself, but got some information online.

There are a few [cafes](https://www.sabihagokcen.aero/passengers-and-visitors/passenger-guide/cafes-and-restaurants) on arrivals level.

- Caribou Coffee
- Karafırın
- Simit Sarayı
- Burger King
- McDonalds
- Starbucks

I cannot see any [lounges](https://www.sabihagokcen.aero/passengers-and-visitors/before-flight/cip-and-lounges) on arrivals level, all of them are on departures level.

- ISG CIP Lounge ([Priority Pass](https://www.prioritypass.com/en/lounges/turkey/istanbul-sabiha-gokcen-intl/saw-lgm-international-cip-lounge)) - domestic & international departures air side
- Lounge Istanbul International - international departures mezzanine level
- Turkish Airlines Lounge - domestic travelling passengers

Comment: Is there space to sit down or are these just serving "hole in the wall" style? Where are these location wise? This answer doesn't help me much.

Comment: @chx I don't have further information. Sorry.